# Stop execute jsp page query when forwarded request and response from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

1. In my jsp page have select query based on Id and those values assign to text box value.
2. I have servlet page aslo in servlet page i did update query and dsiplaying message redirect to jsp page.
3. when i redirect from servlet to jsp in my jsp page it again exccutes jsp page in select query here id value is null it shows all textboxes null value.
   how can i do this without excuting jsp select query with id value is null

Jsp page:

```
 <%
 Connection conn = null;
Statement st;
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource(); 
        connections
      conn = ds.getConnection();
      st=conn.createStatement();
      if(request.getQueryString() != null){      
         String Batch1=request.getQueryString();
        String Id1=request.getParameter("Id");        
             String s ="select columns from Table where Id="+Id1+"and BatchID="+BatchId1+"";
            st = conn.createStatement();             
                ResultSet res;   
               PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(s); 
                res=prep.executeQuery();           
                String col1=null;
                String col2=null;                         
                while(res.next()){          
              TicketNum = res.getString("col1");
              PatientName = res.getString("col2");                     
                }               
              request.setAttribute("col1",col1); 
             request.setAttribute("col2",col2);             
      }
                %>
  <input type="text" id="txtBatchName" class="form-control" name="txtBatchName" value="<%=request.getParameter("Id")%>"/>
//same like that all text boxes
  <% 

                     }
                    catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }   %>
```

my servlet redirect page:

```
if(i>0)             
            request.setAttribute("message", "Successfully Updated!...");      
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Update.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: don't execute your snippets on your jsp pages. It's a place for HTML data, not Java. Do this in your servlet and use `request.setAttribute()` to supply your jsp with data. By this, you can decide which content is being displayed on your jsp page.

Comment: Hi,@KarelG, Here i am redirecting one page to another page at page load only i need to assign values to textboxes  so i take in jsp page(like page oad). Can you tell me where i write in page load instead of jsp page thank you